# CLI launch chrome at url without https protocol prefix

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, bash, zsh

I'm trying to write a script, and failing pretty miserably

My script looks like this (I wish it could be `jira open` not `jira_open` btw):

```
jira_open () {
  autoload -Uz vcs_info
  precmd () { vcs_info }
  setopt prompt_subst
  open -a "Google Chrome" "jira.corp.asdf.com/browse/$vcs_info_msg_0_"
}
```

Chrome is trying to open the argument as a file, and it's saying the file doesn't exist

Please help

Comment: what scripting language is this ?

Comment: zsh, but it could be bash

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out that the jira domain is actually hosted through `http://` since it's over VPN and de-facto secure and only my earlier attempt with `https://` wasn't working

I naively assumed the protocol didn't exist, but prefixing with `http://` fixed the problem

https://superuser.com/a/422861/347101

this works fine:

```
jira_open () {
  autoload -Uz vcs_info
  precmd () { vcs_info }
  setopt prompt_subst
  open -a "Google Chrome" "http://jira.corp.asdf.com/browse/$vcs_info_msg_0_"
}
```