# Launching Chrome with url containing quesiton mark

Tags: windows, command-line, google-chrome, batch, batch-file

I have been using [this](https://superuser.com/questions/153245/how-can-i-open-google-chrome-via-command-line-with-a-url-in-incognito-mode) as reference to create a  bat file to launch chrome with a predetermined url path but there is an issue I am having with this.

Here are the contents of my bat file

```
start "google" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files "H:\testsite\index.html?cd0=../test.txt&auto=1"
```

The problem is that Chrome launches to H:\testsite\index.html%3Fcd0=../test.txt&auto=1 instead of H:\testsite\index.html?cd0=../test.txt&auto=1 which means the page cannot be found. i need to manually replace the %3F with a ? to get it to work.

How can I resolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `file:///` in your string path//file:

```
start "google" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files "file:///H:\testsite\index.html?cd0=../test.txt&auto=1"
```